# XMPPHP as live support chat

Tags: php, xmpp, pidgin, xmpphp

My idea is to integrate a live support chat on a website. The users text is send with xmpphp to my jabber client with the jabberbot sender id and if I answer, the jabber bot, takes my answer and transfers the text to the user.

There is only one problem. How do I separate different users or different chats? I don't want all users to see the answer, but the user who asks. Is there a kind of unique chat id or another possibility, that I might just missed?

User => Website => Chatbot => me

I want to answer and send it back to the user, but how can I find out the correct user from my answer?

Comment: I don't see what you are missing here!! it depends, are you saving your chat in files (including xml) or database, and if so what is the structure that you have built?

Comment: The problem is to send my answer from the chatbot to the right user.

Comment: ok, I told you it depends on the relation between the users and the chats. so what have you considered?

Comment: You get the problem. :-) I can generate some kind of session id, but how do I keep it consistent inside the chat protokoll?

Comment: if you meant do I get the problem. actually not that much. still not clear for me what is your need.

Comment: Let's say, a user comes to my webpage, clicks the chat button, types some text. The text is sent to my jabber messenger. So far so good. Now, I answer, chatbot receives the answer. How can the chatbot find out, which user is waiting for this answer?

Comment: considering that with each process (chat message sending and receiving) assign a unique id (or token) that is already copied a reference to the user identification, so your jabber will now know what user should receive the message back.

Comment: consider using a Javascript XMPP library like Strophe instead of XMPPHP

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan And then I have to write it by hand in front of every message? @ alex And this will change what, except I have to write the login data on the homepage?

Comment: you can make a function to do your work. a function that triggered whenever someone makes a chat message.

Comment: Ok, from the beginning: 1. A user XY starts a chat and sends a text message 2. I receive the message 3. I answer 4. A bot receives my answer 5. The user receives my answer from the bot. I can of course send an id with my message from the user, but that is not my problem. My problem is, how I can be sure, that my answer is sent to the user with the open chat window and not to anyone else with an open chat window. I receive an id, but I'd have to put this id in front of my answer, so the bot knows - this is for User XY. That's why I ask, if the session is somehow unique, so that I can use that.

Comment: @Oliver: your application will scale much better. Because the Xmpp library is running on the client (browser), and not on your server.

Comment: Oliver, are you concerned about a specific implementation using the exact two products you've mentioned (Jabber and XMPPHP), or are you asking about the *routing* of and message queueing/pub-sub contracts between connected resources (for instance, a lot of sys admins use chat terminals to manage remote resources through "chat" commands)? The latter I could I do, but the former I've not had any experience. If you're open to other approaches or setups, though...

Comment: Some quick research showed that XMPP uses the username to address messages to. What you probably want to do is create an unique username for every session, and then messages would not be shown to all users, as when they share a username.

Comment: Have you also taken a look at the RFCs that specify XMPP? They are available here http://xmpp.org/xsf/press/2004-10-04.shtml, and probably mainly https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3920.txt is relevant.

Comment: A solution would be: When a new client do a request, create a random session id, write this into databse (mysql, memcached, whatever). 
Table 1:  ClientName, SessionId, SupporterName (the bot needs first to choose a supporter), LastMessageTime
Table 2:  SessionId, Messge, To (client/supporter)
The have a chat bot running 24/7 as php cli app. 
The bot will read all second the database for new messages to the supporter and send this mesages and messages from the supporter needs to written to the database. 
But with this solution a supporter can only have one client at the same time.

Comment: To have multiply clients at the same time for one supporter, you nees to send only a XMPP message to one or more supporter with a link to web chat. Then lets chat the supporter with an web app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I have to solve this problem I used this architecture:

[image]

[Entlarge image](http://i48.tinypic.com/wgu81g.png)

The Webserver provides an JavaScript / jQuery or flash chat.

After chat is started, the client ask the server all 1 Second for new Messages.

### Alternative for 1 Sec Polling

If that is to slow for you, have a look at [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

http://martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial

http://demo.cheyenne-server.org:8080/chat.html

But Websockets could no provided by php. There for you need to change php + apchache agaist [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) or [java](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket).

### Plain HTTP PHP Methode

In PHP you will connect to the [PsyBnc](http://www.psybnc.at/) with is polling the messages from the supporter for you.

The [PsyBnc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_%28software%29) is an [IRC](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/cgi-bin/rfc/rfc1459.html) bot.

The reason why don't directly connect to XMPP or BitlBee is that those protocols don't like the flapping connect, disconnect from PHP. Because you can not keep the session alive, you need something that is made for often and short connects. This is the PsyBnc.

I would use something like this:

http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SmartIRC/download

```
<?php
session_start();

$message = $_GET['message'];
$client_name = $_GET['client_name'];

if (empty($_SESSION['chat_id'])) {
    $_SESSION['chat_id'] = md5(time(). mt_rand(0, 999999));
}

if (empty($_SESSION['supporter'])) {
    // how do you select the supporter? 
    // only choose a free?
    // We send first message to all supporter and the first who grapped got the chat (where only 3 gues)
}

$irc_host = "127.0.0.1";
$irc_port = 6667; // Port of PsyBnc
$irc_password = "password_from_psy_bnc";
$irc_user = "username_from_psy_bnc";

include_once('Net/SmartIRC.php');

class message_reader
{
    private $messages = array();

    public function receive_messages(&$irc, &$data)
    {
        // result is send to #smartirc-test (we don't want to spam #test)
        $this->messages[] = array(
            'from' => $data->nick, 
            'message' => $data->message,
        );  
    }

    public function get_messages() {
        return $this->messages;
    }
}

$bot = &new message_reader();
$irc = &new Net_SmartIRC();
$irc->setDebug(SMARTIRC_DEBUG_ALL);
$irc->setUseSockets(TRUE);
$irc->registerActionhandler(SMARTIRC_TYPE_QUERY|SMARTIRC_TYPE_NOTICE, '^' . $_SESSION['chat_id'], $bot, 'receive_messages');
$irc->connect($irc_host, $irc_port);
$irc->login($_SESSION['chat_id'], $client_name, 0, $irc_user, $irc_password);
$irc->join(array('#bitlbee'));
$irc->listen();
$irc->disconnect();

// Send new Message to supporter
if (!empty($message)) {
    $irc->message(SMARTIRC_TYPE_QUERY, $_SESSION['supporter'], $message);
}

echo json_encode(array('messages' => $bot->get_messages()));
```

### Connect the support instant messanger to PHP

We have allready an IRC connection to the PsyBnc, now we need to send messages from IRC to ICQ, XMPP, GOOGLE TALK, MSN, YAHOO, AOI...

Here for is a nice solution named [BitlBee](http://www.bitlbee.org/main.php/news.r.html).
BitlBee offers an IRC Server with can transfer message from and to nearly all instant messager protocols. By aliasing those accounts. For example you need for your system only 1 Server account at google talk, icq ... and at all your supporter to the buddylist of those accounts. Now BitleBee will provide your [boddylist](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qqoM_kKFuk) as an irc chat.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are rather confusing. As Joshua said, you don't need a Jabber bot for this. All you need is a Jabber server - which you should already have. What you do is, you create a volatile user account *sessionid*@*yourdomain.com* whenever the chat feature is used and then you can just reply to any incoming message like normal while your website client can fetch the messages meant for it whenever.

Alternatively you could create one user account - qa@*yourdomain.com* - and use XMPP resource identifiers for the routing part. XMPP allows for something like qa@*yourdomain.com*/*sessionid* and you should be able to tell your XMPP library to only query a specific resource. Most XMPP client software will also reply to a specific resource by default and open a new conversation when applicable. This method is less "clean" than the first, but it would work somewhat better if you can't arbitrarily create user accounts for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what XMPP server you are using, but you could also try the [Fastpath plugin and webchat for Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp).  Which is meant to provide a support team service over XMPP.

That being said, your question itself seems to imply nothing more than the standard chat feature of XMPP, which is between two users.  It just means that the support person has a unique chat with each user asking a  question.  No other user will see that conversation.